# pause javascript until popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I want to do something like this:

```
/*do something*/
var returnValue = /*open a popup window*/
/*do something with return value*/
```

I found `showModalDialog` can make this work, here's the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cMQg2/):

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    var w = window.showModalDialog("about:blank",window , "");
    alert("popup closed!");
});
```

But unfortunately safari on iPad does not support `showModalDialog`. The only way I can imagine is:

**in parent window**

```
window.callback = /*callback function after the popup closed*/
/*open a popup window*/
```

**in child window**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.opener.callback.call()
}
```

But using callback makes the code hard to read. Is there a better way to pause the javascript until the popup window is closed?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wrote your popup message through js & jquery

Comment: I'm sorry: JavaScript IS callbacks. And NodeJS is more callbacks ;) In this case I'd create my own modal (or have a look at Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/), which would be triggered by some event (button click etc) and I'd attach an event to it being confirmed and do something with the value entered by the user. You cannot just *stop* JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for answering.Callback seems to the only solution

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you use jQuery. If you're allowed to use jQueryUI as well you can utilize the jqueryui dialog widget:

JS

```
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
     autoOpen:false,
     close: function() {alert('window closed')} //your "on close" logic here
  });  

  $( "#test" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog" title="My Dialog">
    <p>my content </p>
</div>
<button id="test">open blocking popup</button>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqJ2s/)

Comment: Thanks for answering,but this is a callback solution.I want something that can pause javascript like showModalDialog